# CUDA 4.0 run time problems

Tags: linker, runtime, cuda

I have a computer on which I installed CUDA 3.2 and worked with successfuly.
I have lately installed CUDA 4.0, but any program that use the CUDA 4.0 libraries(such as cudart.lib) has run time issues, specifically Initialization Error.
This also happen in a sample from the computing SDK 4.0(deviceQuery). If I take the sample from the 4.0 SDK, and link the 3.2 lib instead, then it runs perfectly.
I have uninstalled CUDA Toolkit 3.2, but it seems somewhere 3.2 still dominate the run time.
Any idea what I should do?

Comment: Could you please add the exact error you're getting. It sounds like a dynamic library problem, so if you're sure that CUDA 4.0 libraries are installed well, maybe your path does not include these libraries. Anyway, please post your error.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say anything about the driver version you are using but I only got that error when I had the wrong driver version. Go to the CUDA downloads page http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-40 and get the latest driver (270.81). Should work.

Comment: Yep, the current windows WHQL driver is broken, use the developer driver for now.

Comment: I am not sure which driver to use. I have both a Geforce and a Tesla, so I installed the Tesla driver since it's the one running CUDA. (I think the Tesla driver is the same version as the developer driver?)

Comment: I never worked with a Tesla card but as far as I know, the developer driver is the same for every CUDA enabled card.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having difficulties setting up the environment in Visual Studio, refer here: [CUDA 4.0 Issues](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/03/09/nvidia-cuda-4-0-tips-and-issues/)